# How do I register component globally in Quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I have a component which I'll be using in every page of my web-app. To simplify my work how do I register this component globally? I used nuxt once and it was so easy by npm `@nuxtjs/global-components`. What is process with Quasar? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a boot file with all your global components, e.g. `global-components.js`

There you need to import your components and apply them to Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from '../component/MyComponent.vue'

Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)
```

Lastly you need to call your boot file in `quasar.conf.js`

```
boot: ["global-components"]
```

[More info](https://quasar.dev/app-extensions/tips-and-tricks/provide-a-ui-component)

Comment: This works. I had to do `export default ({ app }) => {  app.component('my-component',  MyComponent)}` in the boot file to make it work

Comment: how do you do this using quasar CDN

Answer (score 18):

In Quasar 2:

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent.vue'

export default boot(async ({ app }) => {
  app.component('my-component', MyComponent)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this solution and it helps us to dynamically register component

Create a file in src/boot folder for example i created `register-my-component.js` and white this code:

```js
// src/boot/register-my-component.js
import upperFirst from "lodash/upperFirst";
import camelCase from "lodash/camelCase";

export default ({ app }) => {
  const requireComponent = require.context(
    "src/components",
    true,
    /[A-Z-_]\w+\.(vue)$/
  );

  requireComponent.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName);
    const componentName = upperFirst(
      camelCase(
        fileName
          .split("/")
          .pop()
          .replace(/\.\w+$/, "")
      )
    );
    app.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig);
  });
};
```

Now register this boot file in `quasar.conf.js`. you can find it in the root directory

```js
// app boot file (/src/boot)
// --> boot files are part of "main.js"
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
boot: [ ..., "register-my-component" ],
```

Now you don't need to import and register components anymore (NOTE: as you can see only components in src/component register automatically. So if you write your component in other paths you need to import and register that)